# Docker GPU enabled version (>19.03) does not load tensorflow successfully

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I want to use docker 19.03 and above in order to have GPU support. I currently have docker 19.03.12 in my system. I can run this command to check that Nvidia drivers are running:

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
Wed Jul  1 14:25:55 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.64       Driver Version: 430.64       CUDA Version: N/A      |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 26%   54C    P5    13W / 180W |    734MiB /  8119MiB |     39%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also, if run locally my module works with GPU support just fine. But if I build a docker image and try to run it I get a message:

> ```
> ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

I am using cuda 9.0 with tensorflow 1.12.0 but I can switch to cuda 10.0 with tensorflow 1.15.
As I get it the problem is that I am probably using a previous dockerfile version with commands which does not make it compatible with new docker GPU enabled version (19.03 and above).
The actual commands are these:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-base-ubuntu16.04

# Pick up some TF dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        cuda-command-line-tools-9-0 \
        cuda-cublas-9-0 \
        cuda-cufft-9-0 \
        cuda-curand-9-0 \
        cuda-cusolver-9-0 \
        cuda-cusparse-9-0 \
        libcudnn7=7.0.5.15-1+cuda9.0 \
        libnccl2=2.2.13-1+cuda9.0 \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libhdf5-serial-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libzmq3-dev \
        pkg-config \
        software-properties-common \
        unzip \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1604-4.0.1-ga-cuda9.0 && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install libnvinfer4=4.1.2-1+cuda9.0
```

I could not find a docker base file for fundamental GPU usage either.

In [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10776) there was a proposal for exposing `libcuda.so.1` but it did not work in my case.

So, is there any workaround for this problem or a base dockerfile to adjust to?

My system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit:

I just noticed that nvidia-smi from within docker does not display any cuda version:

```
CUDA Version: N/A
```

in contrast with the one locally run. So, this probably means that no cuda is loaded inside docker for some reason I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;**

A base Dockerfile which seems to work with docker 19.03+ & cuda 10 is this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-base
```

which can be conbined with tf 1.14 but for some reason could not found tf 1.15.

I just used this Dockerfile to test it:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-base
CMD nvidia-smi
```

**longer answer:**

Well, after a lot of trials and errors (and frustration) I managed to make it work for docker 19.03.12+cuda 10 (although with tf 1.14 not 1.15).

I used the code from [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-properly-use-the-gpu-within-a-docker-container-4c699c78c6d1) and used the base Dockerfiles provided there.

First I tried to check the `nvidia-smi` from within docker using Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-base
CMD nvidia-smi

$docker build -t gpu_test .
...
$docker run -it --gpus all gpu_test
Fri Jul  3 07:31:05 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.64       Driver Version: 430.64       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 45%   65C    P2   142W / 180W |   8051MiB /  8119MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which finally seems to find cuda binaries: `CUDA Version: 10.1`.

Then, I made a minimal Dockerfile which could test the successful loading of tensorflow binary libraries within docker:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-base

# The following are just declaring variables and ultimately use
ARG USE_PYTHON_3_NOT_2=True
ARG _PY_SUFFIX=${USE_PYTHON_3_NOT_2:+3}
ARG PYTHON=python${_PY_SUFFIX}
ARG PIP=pip${_PY_SUFFIX}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ${PYTHON} \
    ${PYTHON}-pip

RUN ${PIP} install tensorflow_gpu==1.14.0

COPY bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN chmod a+rwx /etc/bash.bashrc

WORKDIR /src
COPY *.py /src/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "tf_minimal.py"]
```

and tf_minimal.py was simply:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
```

and for completeness I just post the bashrc file I am using:

```
# Copyright 2018 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
# ==============================================================================

export PS1="\[\e[31m\]tf-docker\[\e[m\] \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[m\] > "
export TERM=xterm-256color
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
alias ls="ls --color=auto"

echo -e "\e[1;31m"
cat<<TF
________                               _______________                
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ / 
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/

TF
echo -e "\e[0;33m"

if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
  cat <<WARN
WARNING: You are running this container as root, which can cause new files in
mounted volumes to be created as the root user on your host machine.

To avoid this, run the container by specifying your user's userid:

$ docker run -u \$(id -u):\$(id -g) args...
WARN
else
  cat <<EXPL
You are running this container as user with ID $(id -u) and group $(id -g),
which should map to the ID and group for your user on the Docker host. Great!
EXPL
fi

# Turn off colors
echo -e "\e[m"
```